# someone who tries to be funny but they're not

Tags: word-request

You've probably come across such *a person who tries to be funny but he can't be because he's not but he thinks he is*. Their jokes are old or simply what they say is not funny, you get the idea. Not that they're weird or bad; actually they turn out to be real sweethearts sometimes but they're just not funny. What do you call such a person?

> Your grandpa is nice but let's face it: he's [**the word**]
>
> Oh man I don't know why he tries so hard to be funny! Why nobody tells him that he's just [**the word**]. That's pathetic!

An adjective, a noun, or a noun phrase will do.

**Edit**: In my native language we have an adjective to describe such a person which literally means ***insipid*** that is used for food, too. Like insipid food which tastes bland, the person who's **insipid* has not much sense of humor as if being funny was like spice making the person **tasteful*. I thought there might be an equivalent in English but I gave up searching after a while and I posted the question.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a word to describe the person, but you could convey a similar thought with: _Your grandpa is nice but **his jokes [fall flat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+flat)**._

Comment: "That's my grandpa.  _He thinks he is funny._"

Comment: What is your native language and what is the word?  I found this because my girlfriend asked about a similar Vietnamese word: vô duyên

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *(just) not funny*.

> Your grandpa is nice but let's face it: he's **just not funny**.

You could also consider *no comedian* or *no one's comedian*.

> Your grandpa is nice but let's face it: he's **no comedian**/**no one's comedian**.

Either suggests that he is not funny by any stretch or anyone's standards.

Comment: Thanks Max. In my native language we have an adjective to describe such a person which literally means _**insipid**_ which is used for food, too. Like insipid food which tastes bland, the person who's _*insipid_ has not much sense of humor as if being funny was like spice making the person _*tasteful_. I thought there might be an equivalent in English but I gave up searching after a while and I posted the question.

Comment: That's very interesting. Consider including this context in your post. I couldn't think of anything similar, but let's see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **dork** or **jerk** or **silly**

> I don't wanna seem like a dork

Comment: Interesting that there are many words (slangs) to call someone rudely, like yours and others like dumbbell, dolt, nerd, airhead, dick, blockhead, oh, I was called douch by an American girl once before. haha.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to them as a [**witling**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/witling). It refers to someone who thinks they're witty (or funny) but they're not.